# Why is my JavaFX PerspectiveCamera Rotating Around a Seemingly Arbitrary Point?

Tags: javafx, camera, rotation, perspectivecamera

I am working on a first-person game, and right now I am building a game engine using JavaFX. I am using the PerspectiveCamera as my player character. However, when I use the default rotation method in JavaFX to rotate my camera, it ends up rotating around some point, moving it far and wide. What I want is for the camera to simply rotate on the spot, and stay in place.

Here is my code:

```
camera.setRotationAxis(new Point3D(camera.getLayoutX() + (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width/2), camera.getTranslateZ(), 0));
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT){
            camera.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(5, camera.getTranslateX(), camera.getTranslateY(), camera.getTranslateZ(), Rotate.Y_AXIS));
            camrot += 5;
            if (camrot > 360) {
                camrot -= 360;
            }
            System.out.println(camrot);;
        }else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT){
            camera.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(-5, camera.getTranslateX(), camera.getTranslateY(), camera.getTranslateZ(), Rotate.Y_AXIS));
            camrot -= 5;
            if (camrot < 0) {
                camrot += 360;
            }
            System.out.println(camrot);
        }
```

Does anyone know what might be wrong here? Maybe something to do with the rotation axis? Not sure, somebody else told me what to put there.

Comment: I believe the problem is you add a new `Rotate` each time, without removing any of them. Each transformation builds on the previous one. Also, I assume you're moving your camera by modifying the translate properties since you use them to determine the pivot point; as your camera moves you'll end up with different pivot points for different `Rotate` transforms. I'm guessing all this combined is causing your problems.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks so much!